# PLACEHOLDER - Convert Slack message to StackOverflow question

Tags: app, placeholder

In open-source communities, users often ask even complex questions in Slack.
Slack isn't the best place for asking technical questions. It's not searchable by Google and requires a monthly subscription in order to search for anything.

We found it convenient to have a "Convert this message to StackOverflow question" button in Slack.

Currently in development.